# Dynamic gridview based on dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a bit of an chicken and an egg.

I need to bind a gridview to a set of database values.  The gridview is dynamic and the columns, cells are created at run time.

As such, I need to re-bind the grid on every postback in the pre-init, init events after very post back.

However, the data used to populate the grid uses a value from a dropdown box on the same page.  As such, the value of dropdown is not accessible through viewstate until after the init event (i.e. the selected index is always the first item in the list until after on init).

How can I get access to the value of the drop down in time to rebind the grid before the pageload event?

Comment: why you want to create DatyaGrid in "init" event, you can create grid on runtime in page load event.

Comment: You can create DataGrid at run time on page load event or in DropDown change event

Comment: the gird is dynamically created and include template fields with checkboxes in them.  If the grid is created in page load then view state is lost, it needs to be created before page load to allow LoadViewState to work.

Answer (score 0):

If the Gridview always has the same number of columns, you could have the dynamic query generate column names as aliases, and then just rebind the Gridview on dropdown change?

Answer (score 0):

you can use and  HtmlHidden control for store the value you need. It doesn't depend by the viewstate and it's available into the page init